# Permutation in tensorflow for parts of the inputs

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I have a NN that takes `inputs = [A, B]`, where `A` and `B` are both Nd-arrays, of shapes `(N, ...)` - i.e. first dimension of size `N` (= number of training events) is aligned.

Now I want to train my NN with inputs `[A, B]` on target `y = np.ones(N)` and `[A, permute(B)]` on `y = np.zeros(N)`.
I can achieve that by constructing my inputs like:

```
inputs = [np.vstack([A, A]), np.vstack(B, np.random.permutation(B)]
y = np.concatenate([np.ones(N), np.zeros(N)])
```

However, that means to do a lot of copying to device. Is there a way to achieve that via tensorflow directly on the device?
I'm aware of `tf.data` and its capability to shuffle, but that does not do what I intend. The training should still happen on shuffled inputs+targets overall.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out one can have multiple, nested shuffling in a `tf.data.Dataset`, which solves the problem.

```
inputs = tf.data.Dataset.zip(
    tf.data.Dataset.concatenate(A, A), 
    tf.data.Dataset.concatenate(B, B.shuffle(N)),
    tf.data.Dataset.concatenate(ones, zeros)
    )
```

and then shuffle all together like so:

```
inputs.shuffle(2*N)
```